# How to extract text within tags in htmlcleaner or jSoup

Tags: android, htmlcleaner

I'm newbie to Android development, can't get to understand HtmlCleaner or jSoup basics.

I have a page, e.g.

```
<html><body>
....(large code here)....
<b>Hello World! </b> 
....(large code here)....
</body> </html>
```

How can I extract the words within `<b>..</b>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use Jsoup this should be pretty easy

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp").get();
Element firstBoldElement = doc.select("b").first();
System.out.println("Bold Text is : "+firstBoldElement.text());
```

You will have to add proper Exception handling to the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Using jSoup. Excuse any mistakes, I wrote this from memory.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(pageString);
Elements eles = doc.getElementsByTag("b");
for(int i = 0; i < eles.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(eles.get(i).text());
}
```

Comment: That's quite nice too. Thanks!